# Package for therefore (∴) symbol on TeX Live Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: math-mode, debian

I'm working with proofs and math and I would like to have a package that contains symbols including therefore.

I'm currently using the Debian distribution of TeX Live, not the native. To my knowledge there is a package called amssymb that contains ∴ but it is not in the list of currently available Debian packages for LaTeX.

For now I found a macro someone created that looks like ∴ but it would be helpful to have a package that can do the same so I don't have to write it in every file.

Please let me know if there is a better place to ask this question or an alternate way to find a persistent solution to this.

Edit: Works now, not sure why it didn't before. Maybe I forgot to include the package.

Comment: https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your preamble (or any package which loads this), you can just write `\therefore` in maths mode. As [Willie Wong says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709723/), if you have even a minimally functional installation of LaTeX, you already have this package.

If you are using non-default text fonts, you might want to use a different set of fonts for maths, too, but `\therefore` will be available in any reasonably comprehensive configuration.

Answer (score 3):

`amssymb` is part of the [`amsfonts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts?lang=en) collection. In Debian it is included as part of the package [`texlive-base`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/texlive-base);  if you've "installed TeXLive" in any reasonable sense of the phrase using the Debian package manager, you should already have the `amssymb` package available on your system.